# Sharpdx Direct2D1 BitmapRenderTarget to Image?

Tags: c#, image, direct2d, sharpdx

I'm looking for an easy way to create images out of Direct2D1 BitmapRenderTarget.

I do have a BitmapRenderTarget like this one:

```
var bitmapRenderTarget = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapRenderTarget(m_d2dRenderTarget, CompatibleRenderTargetOptions.None, new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm, AlphaMode.Premultiplied));
```

I can access the Direct2D1 bitmap itself by using bitmapRenderTarget.Bitmap. Though I'm not able to create a PNG,JPEG,... out of it without using WIC. Could anyone provide me a way to create a System.Drawing.Image out of it?

I would be happy to see an example because of PixelFormat incompatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No apparently there is no way without WIC.

Within SharpDX Samples there are two example project which illustrate how to encode images.

There is a new(ish) one which "can" leverage the hardware by using a `Direct3D11.Device`
https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/Desktop/Direct2D1/OfflineImageProcessingApp/Program.cs

And the old one https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Direct2D1/RenderToWicApp/Program.cs using the `WicRenderTarget`

If you take the code from the first one, you should actually get what you want, still you need Wic to encode the Bitmap to the destination image format (jpg, png...)

Comment: Thanks for those two links. Unfortunately I do have two problems right now. Your link number 1 only works with windows 8 and higher. Link two looks quite good but I did not manage to draw a bitmap created by another direct2d factory. Maybe you could give me a hint? I can also provide more code if it helps.

Comment: No the first one also works on Win7, but you might have to install a small patch. They tweeked/added something to Direct2D in Win8 which is also available for Win7...
2nd one, no I have no clue how to get your d2d target working as wic target. I bet it is not possible and you have to use a wic render target... There is actually no other way I know of.